# Do C debuggers initialise all process memory to 0?

Tags: gdb

I recently came across an intermittent uninitialised pointer issue, which caused a segfault. I tried to debug it using gdb and vscode's built in debugger (cppdbg) but I couldn't replicate it, the issue only occurred when I ran the executable normally. The related code freed a pointer if it wasn't null, and 1/10 runs it happened to be non-null, since it was never initialised. I re-ran the debuggers nearly a hundred times, so I'm a bit curious why the segfault never happened while debugging.

Does gdb/etc initialise process memory to 0 before starting the process?

Comment: I think the answer is no, but don't know for sure (thus just a measly comment). But, this does show why a debugger isn't the tool to track down these sort of fickle errors anyway: memory and address sanitizer is the tool for the job, and they work predictably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does gdb/etc initialise process memory to 0 before starting the process?

No.

Depending on the exact specifics (was the uninitialized pointer on the stack?), it may be an *accident* that the bug didn't show up under debuggers.

Debuggers do change the process environment a bit, so some bugs do show more or less readily under them.

P.S. There are powerful tools, such as Valgrind and Memory Sanitizer which make such bugs quite easy to find.

Comment: The variable was an uninitialized field in a class which was allocated on the stack. I've used valgrind before but I found it difficult. Memory Sanitizer looks a lot easier to use so I'll check it out. Thanks